# Multi attack as part of attack of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Fighters have an archetype called Two Weapon Warrior, which has an ability called Double Strike at 9th Lv. It lets the user attack with both weapon when using Two Weapon Fighting feat as a standard action. Can you you use this ability as part of an attack of opportunity with out Combat Reflexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A Two Weapon Warrior Fighter cannot Doublestrike as an opportunity attack

1. As you've noted, [**Doublestrike**](https://www.paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/coreClasses/fighter.html#doublestrike) is used by taking a **standard action**.
2. An [**opportunity attack**](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#attacks-of-opportunity) is not any kind of action type. It is a single non-action **attack**:

   > An attack of opportunity is a single melee attack

   You cannot take a standard action during or instead of the one attack the OA gives you.

Futhermore, having or not having **Combat Reflexes** doesn't affect this. [Combat Reflexes allows you to take more opportunity attacks](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#combat-reflexes), but each opportunity attack is still only one attack each; it doesn't allow you to make multiple attacks in one opportunity attack. It also doesn't allow using the standard action that would be needed to use Doublestrike.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the 13th level Two-Weapon Warrior ability Equal Opportunity (which allows making an off hand attack with your attack of opportunity)

Answer (score 3):

You could not use Double Strike on an Attack of Opportunity even if you had Combat Reflexes, because an attack of opportunity gives you a free attack and not a free standard action, without which you can't use Double Strike.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

An attack of opportunity (aoo) is a single melee attack. So you only get one strike. Nothing in the description of the archetype changes that.

From the [PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html):

> **Making an Attack of Opportunity:** An attack of opportunity is a *single melee attack, and most characters can only make one per round. You don't have to make an attack of opportunity if you don't want to.
>   You make your attack of opportunity at your normal attack bonus, even
>   if you've already attacked in the round.